# How can I remove whitespace under a figure inside a table?

Tags: tables, white-space

I am building a table where each row contains an image, however when I insert the image I end up with a lot of whitespace under the image and it making the row unnecessarily tall.

A minimum working example of the code would be:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1.9cm,rmargin=3.8cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.7cm}|p{6.2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Process} & \textbf{Separation Conceot} &\textbf{Materials Passed} & \textbf{Typically Rejects} \\ \hline
Microfiltration & \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Images/FloridaGDP.png}& Water and dissolved species & Large particles and micro-organisms  \\ \hline
Ultrafiltation & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{Images/Mobifilt.png} & Water and Salts & Bacteria and macro-molecules such as proteins \\ \hline
Nanofiltration & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{Images/Mobifilt.png} & Water & Dissolved contaminants \\ \hline
Reverse Osmosis & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{Images/Mobifilt.png} & Water & Particles and low molar mass species such as ions \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The first row looks like this:
[image]

Comment: My welcome between the users of LaTeX into the site TeX.SE. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

Add a vspace before the graphic to change the alignment:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1.9cm,rmargin=3.8cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.7cm}|p{6.2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Process} & \textbf{Separation Conceot} &\textbf{Materials Passed} & \textbf{Typically Rejects} \\ \hline
Microfiltration & \vspace{-0.7\ht\strutbox}\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image}& Water and dissolved species & Large particles and micro-organisms  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `adjustbox` package, you can instruct the graphics to be top aligned:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1.9cm,rmargin=3.8cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.7cm}|p{6.2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Process} & \textbf{Separation Conceot} &\textbf{Materials Passed} & \textbf{Typically Rejects} \\ \hline
Microfiltration & \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}& Water and dissolved species & Large particles and micro-organisms  \\ \hline
Ultrafiltation & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck} & Water and Salts & Bacteria and macro-molecules such as proteins \\ \hline
Nanofiltration & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck} & Water & Dissolved contaminants \\ \hline
Reverse Osmosis & \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck} & Water & Particles and low molar mass species such as ions \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]